# Angular binding for map markers and list items

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am pretty new to angular and am not sure how to approach a problem. I want to use the angular-google-maps directive to show a list of markers on a map (let say they are for bars) and also have a list to the side showing the bar names and addresses.

When you click on a list item I want it to highlight the marker or if you highlight the marker I want it to highlight the list item. I had all of this working in Knockout but I am refactoring into angular and am not sure how to get this working?

Does anyone have any examples of this kind of thing, or can give me a nudge in the right direction?

thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

the way I handled this was to keep a list of markers that I had put into the Markers directive.  Then on a click event of a list item I found that marker with an id and changed the icon.  Here is my method. (the find is a method from lo-dash.  _.hasValue is a method from my app that basically extends lo-dash to check for null and undefined):

```
function highlightMarker(id) {
        if (!$scope.locationMarkers || highlightIcon === null) {
            return;
        }

        if (_.hasValue(highlightedLocation)) {
            highlightedLocation.icon = normalIcon;
            if (highlightedLocation.id === id) {
                highlightedLocation = null;
                return;
            }
        }

        highlightedLocation = _.find($scope.locationMarkers, { 'id': id });

        if (highlightedLocation) {
            highlightedLocation.icon = highlightIcon;
        }

    }
```